# getting a payment failed unexpected error in razorpay in react native ios and android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, razorpay

I am integrating a razorpay payment gateway in my react native app
. whenever I'm trying to open a razorpay checkout UI its first open a pop up with a loader and after few secods its gives an error payment failed unexpected error with error code 1
.
below is my razorpay checkout UI code

```
 var options = {
        description: "Credits towards consultation",
        image: "https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png",
        currency: "INR",
        key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
        amount: "100", //`${amount}`,
        name: "Gulb",
        //order_id: order_id, //Replace this with an order_id created using Orders API.
      
        theme: { color: "#53a20e" },
      };
      RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
        .then(async (response) => {
          console.log("this is payment id", response);

          alert("Payment Successfull");
}.catch((error) => {
          // handle failure
          alert(`${error.description}`);
          console.log("this is ", error);
        });
```

also I am getting proper order_id from server and still it shows a same error

for ios it shows - payment failed unexpected error
for android it shows - no appropriate payment method found

Answer (score 1):

I also faced a similar issue while integrating razorpay on my react-native app. But I simply regenerated my key id and key secret and re-ran my app again. The issue magically disappreared.

I hope you solved your problem. But leaving this here in case someone else in the future needs any help.